# How to debug this MySQL stored procedure syntax error?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure in MySQL. I am getting issue in casting a day value from a date into integer value. I need to cast `Day(now())` into integer, as I need to do some manipulation on this value.

Please see below for detail procedure code.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `CREATE_PARTITION_FOR_MONTH`();
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE `CREATE_PARTITION_FOR_MONTH`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE current_month_total_days_count INT;
    DECLARE current_month_days_left INT;
    DECLARE current_day INT;
    DECLARE next_month_first_date DATE ;
    DECLARE loop_start_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE total_days_in_next_month INT;
    DECLARE next_month_var_date DATE;
    DECLARE partition_val VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE range_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET current_month_total_days_count :=  CAST(DAY(LAST_DAY(now())) AS UNSIGNED);
    SET current_day := CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURDATE()) AS UNSIGNED);
    SET current_month_days_left := current_month_total_days_count - current_day;
    SET next_month_first_date := DATE(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),current_month_days_left));
    SET total_days_in_next_month := DAY(LAST_DAY(next_month_first_date));
    SET next_month_var_date := next_month_first_date;
        SET loop_start_val := 0;
    WHILE loop_start_val < total_days_in_next_month DO
            SET next_month_var_date := DATE(ADDDATE(next_month_first_date,loop_start_val));
            SET partition_val :=  CONCAT('p',TO_DAYS(next_month_var_date));
            SET range_val := TO_DAYS(next_month_var_date);
            ALTER TABLE XYZ ADD PARTITION (PARTITION partition_val VALUES LESS THAN (range_val));      
            SET loop_start_val := loop_start_val+1;

    END WHILE;

END //;

DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'range_val INT DEFAULT 0;
>       SET current_month_total_days_count = SELECT CAST(DAY(L' at line 11

Comment: `DELCARE` typo.

Comment: Learn how to read MySQL error messages. Then it is way easier.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Thanks for pointing out error.

Comment: I have further edited the question , I am getting syntax error at
SET next_month_var_date := DATE(ADDDATE(next_month_first_date,loop_start_val));

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line throwing error `*DELCARE* range_val INT DEFAULT 0;` ... `DELCARE` is the issue. Should be `DECLARE`. Funny ...

Comment: I have further edited the question , i am getting syntax error at line 
SET next_month_var_date := DATE(ADDDATE(next_month_first_date,loop_start_val));

Comment: Ok, sure but post that as separate question closing this one.